# Match a permalink PHP Preg_match

Tags: php, regex

How can I match the permalink below it's for routing. need to match the first part statically, the second dynamically.

`/blog/article`, blog will always be blog, article is dependant on what article permalink it is...

I've tried `preg_match('/([0-9a-z-A-Z-_-]+)/', $this->uri, $matches);`

but that only matches the first part, when i need to know what the second part is.

Comment: Use: `#^/blog/([\w-]+)/?$#`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use:

```
preg_match('/^\/blog\/([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)$/', '/blog/article', $matches);

var_dump($matches[1]);
```

or

```
preg_match('/^\/blog\/([\w-]+)$/', '/blog/article', $matches);

var_dump($matches[1]);
```